# What is the best Stack Exchange site for social media/tech industry questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask about the impact of click fraud on Facebook's revenue model. Where would I go to ask this? The [*Startups* Stack Exchange site](https://startups.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't sound like your question is really answerable here.

Best bet is to ask Facebook...

Startups could take a question that was more about the ways startups who run advertising manage their click fraud, but a Facebook specific one is unlikely to have any available information. It's not a startup and Facebook will keep that data to themselves.

Comment: I'll try Quora. Thanks